# How to unpickle file when there is a non-ascii character in the path?

Tags: python, encoding, pickle

I have a pickled file in a path that contains non-ascii characters:

`D:/sämple_dürectory/31.0mm_e_e1.oes`

As you can see, this is on a Windows machine. When I try to unpickle it, I get an encoding error:

```
filename = 'D:/sämple_dürectory/31.0mm_e_e1.oes'
with open(filename, 'rb') as file_in:
    loaded = pickle.load(file_in)
```

results in:

```
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-ff988755db3a> in <module>()
      1 with open(filename, 'rb') as file_in:
----> 2     pickle.load(file_in)

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xca in position 616: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Oddly enough, this is not a problem when I try to open `numpy` array (.npy) in the same location, even when `numpy` actually also uses pickle, so there clearly must be a way how to do it.

Comment: Are you sure the filename is the problem and not the contents of the pickled file? Can you try with a trivial (string-free) file at the same path?

Comment: Oh, string-free file also works. This seems really like a problem with my file. Thank you very much for your tip!

Comment: No worries. I'm not familiar with pickling but the [`encoding` kwarg of `pickle.load`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle.load) seems relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not the path at all, its an issue of the pickled file.

Maybe you pickled with one version of python an tried to unpickle with another?

Try setting the encoding of the pickled object (Only works if you are using python3) like this:

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as file_in:
    d = pickle.load(file_in, encoding='latin1')
```

Maybe try another encoding!

EDIT:

If you are on python 2.7, try:

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as file_in:
    u = pickle._Unpickler(file_in)
    u.encoding = 'latin1'
    p = u.load()
```